# Showing a function is harmonic given some information

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

"Let $a ∈\mathbb C$ and $r > 0$.

Let $f : S(a, r) → R$ be continuous.
Let $g : B(a, r) → R$ be the Poisson integral of $f$. Then

(1) $g$ is harmonic on $B(a, r)$ and

(2) $f \cup g : B(a, r) → R$ is continuous."

The second part regarding continuity is easy enough, but how should I handle the first part? It seems best to show that $g$ is the real part of a holomorphic function on $B(a,r)$ but how would I go about doing this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should explain your notation $S(a,r)$. What does it denote?

Comment: Let me guess!!! :-) $S(a, r)=\{(x-a)^2+(y-a)^2=r^2\}$, while $B(a, r)=\{(x-a)^2+(y-a)^2\le r^2\}$. Also, $f\cup g$ is the function that equals $g$ in the interior of the ball and equals $f$ on the boundary. (@Suven Laljee: I hope my guess is right. I agree with Crostul that you should explain your notations).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro
Thanks for the help. Sorry for unclear notation. S(a,r) is the sphere of radius r about the point a. And B(a,r) is the open ball of radius r about the point a (so <, without equality).

Comment: Do you mean $\overline {B(a,r)}$ in (2)?

Comment: @zhw Yes, sorry about that

Comment: look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel